# selecting dates till current date - mysql

Tags: mysql

Today is 20th Aug 2013.
I want to generate 20 rows which will contain dates from 1st to 20th (whatever would be the current date) of the month by using [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) query.
Count should always start from 1st date of the month and till current date... output would be like, only one column and multiple rows till current date like given below..

```
    Current month
    8/1/13 12:00 AM
    8/2/13 12:00 AM
    8/3/13 12:00 AM
    8/4/13 12:00 AM
    8/5/13 12:00 AM
    8/6/13 12:00 AM
    8/7/13 12:00 AM
    8/8/13 12:00 AM
    8/9/13 12:00 AM
    8/10/13 12:00 AM
    8/11/13 12:00 AM
    8/12/13 12:00 AM
    8/13/13 12:00 AM
    8/14/13 12:00 AM
    8/15/13 12:00 AM
    8/16/13 12:00 AM
    8/17/13 12:00 AM
    8/18/13 12:00 AM
    8/19/13 12:00 AM
    8/20/13 12:00 AM
```

I tried following query but is of no use. Can you please help to find some other workaround for this?

```
DECLARE @startDate DATETIME=CAST(MONTH(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR) + '/' + '01/' +  + CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR) -- mm/dd/yyyy
DECLARE @endDate DATETIME= GETDATE() -- mm/dd/yyyy

;WITH Calender AS 
(
    SELECT @startDate AS CalanderDate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CalanderDate + 1 FROM Calender
    WHERE CalanderDate + 1 <= @endDate
)
SELECT [Date] = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CalanderDate,25) 
FROM Calender
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Comment: Why are you using MySQL for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This too would work by dynamically building a result set of all days, but can work against any existing table you have that has as least 31 days (max for any given month).

```
select
      @curDay := date_add( @curDay, interval 1 day ) as CalendarDay
   from
      ( select @curDay := date_add( DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),
         '%Y-%m-01'), interval -1 day) ) sqlvars,
      AnyTableInYourDatabaseWithAtLeast31Records
   where
      @curDay <= now()
   limit
      31
```

The first part of select @curDay builds whatever the current day is, gets to the first of the month, then subtracts 1 day from it giving you the last day of the previous month.  Then, the outer select @curDay := keeps updating itself by adding 1 day as the CalendarDay result column.  Since its a join to "any table" in your database, it will keep grabbing a MAX of 31 records, but only return where the date is less than or current to now.

Answer (score 0):

Fiddle at

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/28466/1

```
CREATE TABLE CALENDAR(DATE1 DATETIME);

INSERT INTO CALENDAR VALUES ('2013/8/1 12:00:00');
INSERT INTO CALENDAR VALUES ('2013/8/2 12:00:00');
INSERT INTO CALENDAR VALUES ('2013/8/3 12:00:00');
INSERT INTO CALENDAR VALUES ('2013/8/4 12:00:00');....

SELECT DISTINCT DATE1 FROM Calender where MONTH(DATE1)=MONTH(NOW()) and DAYOFMONTH(DATE1) <=DAYOFMONTH(NOW())
```

This gives the output

Answer (score 0):

I like to use tally tables for these sorts of problems, they tend to be pretty fast:

```
DECLARE @startDate DATETIME= CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(GETDATE())-1),GETDATE()),101);
WITH 
 N0 as (SELECT 1 as n UNION ALL SELECT 1)
,N1 as (SELECT 1 as n FROM N0 AS t1 CROSS JOIN N0 AS t2)
,N2 as (SELECT 1 as n FROM N1 AS t1 CROSS JOIN N1 AS t2)
,N3 as (SELECT 1 as n FROM N2 AS t1 CROSS JOIN N2 AS t2)
,N4 as (SELECT 1 as n FROM N3 AS t1 CROSS JOIN N3 AS t2)
,N5 as (SELECT 1 as n FROM N4 AS t1 CROSS JOIN N4 AS t2)
,N6 as (SELECT 1 as n FROM N5 AS t1 CROSS JOIN N5 AS t2)
,nums as (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) as num FROM N6)
SELECT DATEADD(day,num-1,@startDate) as theDate
FROM nums
WHERE num <= DATEDIFF(day,@startDate,GETDATE()) + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try calling this Stored Procedure;

```
    DELIMITER $$

    CREATE PROCEDURE `test`.`GenerateDates` ()

BEGIN
    DECLARE Days INTEGER;
    DECLARE Count INTEGER;  

    SET Days = DATEDIFF(NOW(),CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()),'-',MONTH(NOW()),'-01'));
    SET Count = 0;

    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tempDates;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tempDates
        (
            YourDate Date,
            PRIMARY KEY(YourDate)
        );


    WHILE (Count <= Days) DO
       INSERT INTO tempDates (YourDate) VALUES
       (DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()),'-',MONTH(NOW()),'-01'), INTERVAL Count DAY),'%Y-%m-%d'));
       SET Count = Count + 1;
    END WHILE;

    SELECT * FROM tempDates;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

:) ... or if a table of 31 integers seems like a stretch, how about a table of 10...

```
SELECT * FROM ints;
+---+
| i |
+---+
| 0 |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |
| 6 |
| 7 |
| 8 |
| 9 |
+---+

SELECT DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),'%Y-%m-01')+INTERVAL i2.i*10+i1.i DAY x FROM ints i1, ints i2 HAVING x <= NOW();
+------------+
| x          |
+------------+
| 2013-08-01 |
| 2013-08-02 |
| 2013-08-03 |
| 2013-08-04 |
| 2013-08-05 |
| 2013-08-06 |
| 2013-08-07 |
| 2013-08-08 |
| 2013-08-09 |
| 2013-08-10 |
| 2013-08-11 |
| 2013-08-12 |
| 2013-08-13 |
| 2013-08-14 |
| 2013-08-15 |
| 2013-08-16 |
| 2013-08-17 |
| 2013-08-18 |
| 2013-08-19 |
| 2013-08-20 |
+------------+
```

(still not sure why you'd do this in MySQL)